# PHP SQL read associative array

Tags: php, sql, associative-array

so basically what I want to do is this:
read out filesize stored in table "dbdateien" in column "dateigroesse"

Then I want to make the sum of all the filesizes and substract them from the upload space limit. To show the user: You have 20 mb free storage left!

My problem is when I fetch the result of the query it gives me every value from the array double...

**This is my code:**

```
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=u-jv029", $username, $password);
$stmt3 = $pdo->prepare("SELECT dateigroesse FROM dbdateien");

$stmt3->execute();
$result= $stmt3->fetchAll();

foreach($result as $show){

    foreach($show as $display){
        echo('<br />Value: ' . $display);
    }
}
echo "<br /><br /><br />";
var_dump($result);
```

**This is the result:**

```
Value: 0
Value: 0
Value: 0
Value: 0
Value: 0
Value: 0
Value: 2.29
Value: 2.29
Value: 4.5
Value: 4.5
Value: 1.2
Value: 1.2


array(6) { [0]=> array(2) { ["dateigroesse"]=> string(1) "0" [0]=> string(1) "0" } [1]=> array(2) { ["dateigroesse"]=> string(1) "0" [0]=> string(1) "0" } [2]=> array(2) { ["dateigroesse"]=> string(1) "0" [0]=> string(1) "0" } [3]=> array(2) { ["dateigroesse"]=> string(4) "2.29" [0]=> string(4) "2.29" } [4]=> array(2) { ["dateigroesse"]=> string(3) "4.5" [0]=> string(3) "4.5" } [5]=> array(2) { ["dateigroesse"]=> string(3) "1.2" [0]=> string(3) "1.2" } }
```

I am thankful for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass in the [FETCH_STYLE](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php). It defaults to FETCH_BOTH.

```
$stmt3->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Then you can echo it out with `$show['dateigroesse']`

Comment: Use FETCH_NUM instead of FETCH_ASSOC. Less data is returned here as the keys are numbers instead of column name. You don't need the column names in the case of question above.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was struggeling with this some hours and now it's solved in a few minutes hahaha